# Access Internet from BB10 simulator

Tags: vmware, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

I want to access Internet from my BB10 simulator.

I have changed the setting of the virtual machine and changed the Network Connection type from `NAT` to `Bridged`.

But after this when I restarted the simulator, it is unable to get the IP address. Thus QNX IDE is unable to discover it.

Please suggest how can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: I found it best to leave it on NAT.  I had the same problem when I tried to switch it to bridged, it doesn't appear to work on bridged.

Comment: yeah....is there any way through which this can be made possible

Answer (score 0):

According to an administrator on the blackberry forums you can do the following:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/BB10-Dev-Alpha-Simulator-not-connecting-to-WiFi/td-p/1842579

1) Power down your VM

2) In VMWare select your VM and then click "Edit Virtual Machine Settings"

3) Select Network Adapter

4) Change from NAT to Bridge mode, which will allow the simulator to have direct access your physical network card.

5) Start the simulator again.

Comment: if you have read the question properly, you have to came to know that I have already tried that

Comment: my apologies, I jumped the gun a bit there.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still an issue for you or anyone else; If I understand correctly, when you switch to bridged connection, you do have internet access on your simulator, but the QNX IDE does not find it via device discovery.

I just had the same problem, it can be solved by typing the simulator IP in by hand. Note that you have to use the address that VMWare displays at the very bottom of the content window, not the IP that is set in Development Settings.

I suspect the QNX IDE of only scanning a certain IP range for target devices. Thus, when you switch to bridged mode and your device obtains an arbitrary address in your LAN, it does not (necessarily) fall in that range.